# jquery load function with kwidget (kaltura player)

Tags: javascript, jquery, kaltura

I am loading a html page having kaltura player embed code in jquery using the jquery.load(). The idea is to load the video in the div tag through javascript on the page.

Code in aspx page

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server"></head>
<body>
<script src="images/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function test() {
                    var light = document.createElement('div');
                    light.id = "light";

                    document.body.appendChild(light);

                    $("#light").load("files/test.html");
                        $("#fade").fadeIn();
                        $("#light").fadeIn(1000);
                        $("#close").fadeIn();

                    return false;
                }
            </script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lb" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" Text="test" ></asp:LinkButton>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Test.html file

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="http://www.kaltura.com/p/423851/sp/42385100/embedIframeJs/uiconf_id/11598752/partner_id/423851"></script>
<div id="kaltura_player" style="width: px; height: px;"></div>
<script>
kWidget.embed({
  "targetId": "kaltura_player",
  "wid": "_423851",
  "uiconf_id": "11598752",
  "flashvars": {},
  "entry_id": "1_znvt6hgh"
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Calling function test() from aspx.cs file

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

             lb.OnClientClick = "return test()";

        }
```

Error when i click on button to load the kaltura video in the div(id='light')

**Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'kWidget' is undefined**

Please let me know if we need to include any file or api to overcome this error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade the player version - you're using a really old version. -our latest is v2.31